# compare values in enum java

Tags: java, enums

So here is my situation I am comparing two situations of the WallEnums to the rest of them.

```
import static com.gowallgo.enumtypes.WallEnums.CAW;
"" ( and the rest )


   /**
     * {@link Set} of cancel {@link WallEnums}s
     */
    private static final Set<WallEnums> WALL_CODES = asSet(RES, CAW, AAP, ASV, CQP, OQR);


// more stuff and then I use it here . 

if (wallEnum != WALL_CODES.contains(wallEnum)){}
```

this begs for refactoring . where should I start so I don't need to make a static import for each code ?

Comment: What do you not like?

Comment: `import static com.gowallgo.enumtypes.WallEnums.*` ?

Comment: Use `Enum.values()`?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `if (wallEnum != WALL_CODES.contains(wallEnum)){}` compare an enum value to a boolean?

Comment: Well, the question title doesn't match the actual question and this is a code review request, so you might want to ask it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @tom there is not quite enough to review here

Comment: Use `if (WALL_CODES.contains(wallEnum)) { }`

Comment: I think in the long term I did not like the fact I was using a Enum and making it into a Set , then having to type out all the Enum's individually. I think @Magnamag suggestion of using an enumset was what I needed to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
// Do not import anything

// This creates a Set that contains all posible values
// In case you need a subset use: EnumSet.of(WallEnums.RES, WallEnums.CAW, etc)
private static final Set<WallEnums> WALL_CODES = EnumSet.allOf(WallEnums.class);

// Later...
if (WALL_CODES.contains(someWallEnum)) {
    // Do stuff if someWallEnum belongs to WALL_CODES set
}
```

This code creates a set of enums using optimized `EnumSet` class. Then you could use any `Set` operation as usual, i.e `contains()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import every enum value you can use

```
import com.gowallgo.enumtypes.WallEnums

WallEnums enum = WallEnums.RES;  //Now you have to use EnumName.VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to import each enum type, You could try importing every element of enum using:

```
import static com.gowallgo.enumtypes.WallEnums.*;
```

Comment: The code environment does not allow imports with a star ( idk why , just one of those glitch type things )  I should have mentioned this.